# How to avoid silent app installations

Tags: applications, security, installation

I have gone through this post [Silent app installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438637/silent-installation-on-android-devices) wherein it clearly mentions it's highly impossible to self install the application without going through the whole installer proceedure.But when i read this one
[Remotely Installing Unwanted Apps on Devices](http://www.xda-developers.com/micromax-remotely-installing-unwanted-apps-on-devices/)
i didn't understand how this is even possible

I am aware of the android applications run in a sand box environment so one application cannot install/interfere another until and unless it has an process Id or something/referencing and also should have the user permissions to do so but with the recent silent app installation  by some OEM is making me doubt about this security issue.

When one app can then why can't other apps follow suit .

Please avoid answers like don't use Internet at all/root the phone/stop purchasing the devices of that particular make ,company.
The above link might help in some clear understanding

Comment: What OEM? Manufacturers usually use system applications to install/update their own apps. The system has permission to install applications and thus doesn't need any confirmation (Play Store also but it asks because of good manner).

Comment: I am speaking not about the bloatware which they update but installing a different application.Check the update

Comment: Play Store no longer asks, and is presently installing its new "feature" without permission called:  Google Play services for Instant Apps. So yes, your security concerns are valid. And also there's this neat thing called Planned Obsolescence, which makes your phone grow slower over time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is using an firewall or manually read every permission for every app installed on your phone and use an permission revoker app both requires root.

You will search for any app that have the permission "download files without notification" and either revoke that permission (it might cause some bugs) or either just block them out of the internet using an firewall like AFWall+

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, if your OEM or carrier includes software that does it on the /system partition, there is nothing you can do without root.
So, your options are
    * root
    * petition them to stop doing it
    * don't get phones from them
No other way around it

Answer (score -2):

Your OEM pre-installed the Software Update app with root access. Without root access, an app cannot start installing another app without the user's explicit permission.

Comment: Root access is mostly *not* how it works. Those applications (services, agents, daemons or how they are called) use their system permissions to install other applications. Every system application (most notably `Package Installer`) can install applications.